Is it possible to have a healthcheck page accessible during heavy loading of an API using Flask_restx?
I have an API built in Flask_restx that requires approximately 10 minutes to load various machine learning models. During this period, I need an accessible endpoint to satisfy the healthcheck needs in the context of the ECS Application Load Balancer in the AWS cloud.
My codes are executed using the flask run command and I have the following information as reference:
Project structure:
-app 
|-src 
|--app 
| |--api 
| | |- codes ... 
| |--models 
| | |- codes ... 
| |--azureml 
| | |- codes ... 
| |--__init__.py 
| |--config.py 
|-run.py 
|-Dockerfile 

Python Codes:
run.py
import os
from app import create_app, API_NAME
from datetime import datetime

env = os.getenv("FLASK_ENV", "development")
app = create_app(env)

@app.shell_context_processor
def shell():
    return {"envConfigs": env}

src/app/init.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app.config import get_config
from app.azureml.artefatos import artefatos
from datetime import datetime

API_NAME = "MyApp"
cors = CORS()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
db = SQLAlchemy()
artefatosML = artefatos() # Here we have hard loading

def create_app(config_name):

    app = Flask(API_NAME)
    app.config.from_object(get_config(config_name))
    
    from app.api import api_bp
    
    app.register_blueprint(api_bp)
    cors.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    
    return app

I tried strategies such as using multithreads, but I was unable to understand compatibility with the already developed structure since I don't use:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

I also tried reversing the order in which the models are instantiated based on the definition of the create_app() function, but it is still not possible to define an accessible endpoint.

you can create seperate service for your ai models

Originally I use microservices for each AI model. The problem is that this generated a lot of maintenance costs and that's why I decided to test a monolithic architecture.

not microservice for each model, but monolith for all ai models and another monolith for   other operational/functional service can be use to health check and then communicate these two service all together

In this case, wouldn't the service for AI models suffer from the same problem as healthcheck? It would take the same 10 minutes for all models to be loaded and in the meantime I would not be able to check their integrity.

Can you load the models asynchronously? Threads?

I didn't tried. Can you show how to do?
